# VERSÃO DA LINGUAGEM C#

Tags: c#, .net

Olá,
quando eu crio um projeto, no visual studio, ele me  fornece a opção para escolher a versão do .Net(...4.5, 4.6, 4.7...) que eu queira utilizar, mas não informa a versão  da linguagem c#(...6, 7...). No python eu obtenho essa informação com o comando python --version. Existe algum comando, no visual studio, que eu possa saber qual a versão do c#? E como eu posso escolher em qual versão escrever o código?